# How do I find a continuous solution for this linear equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, initial-value-problems

So I'm trying to find a continuous solution for this equation:
$dy/dx+y=f(x)$, $f(x)=1$ if $0<=x<=1$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $x>1$ $y(0)=1$. Now I know that this is a linear equation that I have to solve but I'm not sure how to set up the equation and what type of linear equation this is so I don't know how I would solve this. Also what does it mean to find a continuous solution?

Answer (score 1):

"To find a continuous solution" means: find a solution $y_1(x)$ for $0\le x\le1$ with the given initial condition $y_1(0)=1$, then find a solution $y_2(x)$ for $x>1$ taking as initial condition the value of $y_1(1)$. The global solution is continuous on $[0,+\infty)$.